# Como usar dos botones submit en template django

Tags: django, django-urls

Quiero implementar dos botones de tipo submit en el template de Django

Tengo un formulario que me muestra los objetos creados en la base de datos

```
class CampanaElectoralForm(forms.Form):
campana_electoral = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=CampanaElectoral.objects.all(), label="Campaña electoral")


def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CampanaElectoralForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['campana_electoral'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'select2'})
```

Ya tengo un botón que va a una vista, la cual hace un filtrado según la opción seleccionada del formulario, este botón actualmente esta funcionando.

Ahora estoy necesitando agregar un segundo botón que llame a otra vista y le envié como parámetro el value del la opción seleccionada en el formulario

Actualmente lo estoy haciendo de esta forma, pero no funciona

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
        {% crispy form %}
        <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" class="btn btn-success"
               onclick=this.form.action="{% url 'estadisticas/' %}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Informe Ejecutivo" class="btn btn-success"
               onclick=this.form.action="{% url 'reportes/informe_ejecutivo/' %}"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: lo puedes hacer con javascript que tome la decisión, te gustaria ver la respuesta?

Comment: Si, por favor. Te agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En un formulario no pueden existir dos `submit`, el truco para esto es cambiar el type `submit` a `button` , y con una funcion JavaScript pasar la url cambiar el action y hacer el `submit`

Lo escrito vuelto codigo!

```js
function enviarPost( url){
  console.info("inicio validacion del form>>");

  console.info("fin  validacion del form<<");
  var formulario = document.mi_formulario;
  formulario.action = url;
  formulario.submit();
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="mi_formulario">
      <input type="text" name="q"/>
        <input type="button" value="Buscar en SoEs" class="btn btn-success" onclick="enviarPost( 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/search')"/>___
        <input type="button" value="Buscar en Yahoo" class="btn btn-success" onclick="enviarPost( 'https://yahoo.com/search/')"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias. Es lo que necesitaba, te agradezco.

Answer (score 1):

Solo es cosa de declararlo en distinto href cada input.

```
<input type="submit" value="Filtrar" href="{% url 'estadisticas/' %}"/> 
<input type="submit" value="Informe" href="{% url 
                                    'reportes/informe_ejecutivo/'%}"/>
```